# What is this plant with leaves like a cattail but with triangular waxy pods?

Tags: identification, wildflowers

I found this plant near a river in Wisconsin. The leaves look like a cattail but this thing grows pods! The pods are triangular and are waxy and smooth at the same time. The leaves are very much like a cattail.

[image].

Answer (score 2):

It's a little hard for me to tell from the photo, but I suspect that you have a wild iris. Blue flag and yellow flag irises can both be found in the wetlands and near bodies of water in Wisconsin.